# Regex to remove spaces inside braces

Tags: regular-expressions

I have many files with the many of the following forms:

```
export function foo(payload={}) {
  return { type: bar, payload };
}
```

I would like to do a `regex-replace` that removes the spaces between the brackets so that the above becomes (note the removed spaces in the return clause):

```
export function foo(payload={}) {
  return {type: bar, payload};
}
```

In `regex-builder` I can get matches with the following:

```
"{ \\(.*?\\) }"
```

But when I try to do any kind of `regex-replace` across the file, with a replace pattern like `{\1}` I get 0 matches.

Flummoxed.

Comment: `.*` matches any chars except newlines, which includes brace chars. (And please show exactly what you tried. That can help others help you.)

Comment: Maybe try: `"{\\s+\\([^}]*\\)\\s+}"` instead?

Comment: When you call an interactive regexp command, you should not specify double backslashes. They are used only in elisp strings where `\\ ` means a backslash, `\n ` means a newline etc.

Comment: Not that this is your problem, but I don't think the non-greedy modifier ? helps you in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First be sure that your cursor is before the region you want to work on or that you highlight it.

```
{ +\(.*\) +}
```

worked for me.